# Is there any way to know the size of L1, L2, L3 cache and RAM in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

Is there any way to know the size of L1, L2, L3 cache and RAM in ubuntu?

Any terminal command or files I could look into?

Comment: Try superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com. This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

usually I run **dmidecode** for this